# Import is underlined with red in gradle project

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle

I've installed *Eclipse Buildship* (Eclipse Plugin for Gradle) and created new Gradle project in Eclipse. All works well and I can run application using gradle run configuration:

[image]

[image]

but the problem is that in the code editor the dependency (imported library) is underlined with red:

[image]

The exact message that eclipse displays when hovering the red part:

[image]

How to fix it?

Comment: Please also include the exact message that eclipse displays when hovering the red part. You probably messed up your project setup.

Comment: @Zabuza, I've included the screenshot with the message and updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does your `build.gradle` file have `apply plugin: 'eclipse'`? If not, add it.

Then run the gradle task `gradlew cleanEclipse eclipse`